# Некорректная пагинация в Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, pagination

В пагинации на страницах отображаются дубли страниц....( 1 1 2 3).

Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
pagination.php
<?php
class Pagination {
public $total = 0;
public $page = 1;
public $limit = 9999;
public $num_links = 3;
public $url = '';
public $text_first = '1';
public $text_last = '&gt;|';
public $text_next = '&gt;';
public $text_prev = '&lt;';

public function render() {
      /* echo '<pre>';
        var_dump(isset($_GET['route'])); 
        echo '</pre>';
        die();*/
        if(isset($_GET['route'])){


        $takeArea = explode('/',$_GET['route']);

        switch ($takeArea[0]) {
            case 'catalog':
            case 'common':





    if ($this->page < 1) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $this->page;
    }

    if (!(int)$this->limit) {
        $limit = 10;
    } else {
        $limit = $this->limit;
    }

    $num_links = $this->num_links;
    $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

    $output = '<ul class="pagination">';

    if ($page > 1) {
        $tmp_url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->url);
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', rtrim( str_replace('page={page}', '', $tmp_url), '?&')) . '">' . $this->text_first . '</a></li>';
        if ($page == 2){
            $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', rtrim( str_replace('page={page}', '', $tmp_url), '?&')) . '">' . $this->text_prev . '</a></li>';
        }else{
            $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $page - 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_prev . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
            $start = 1;
            $end = $num_pages;
        } else {
            $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
            $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

            if ($start < 1) {
                $end += abs($start) + 1;
                $start = 1;
            }

            if ($end > $num_pages) {
                $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                $end = $num_pages;
            }
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $output .= '<li class="active"><span>' . $i . '</span></li>';
            } else {
                if ($i == 1){
                    $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', rtrim( str_replace('page={page}', '', $tmp_url), '?&')) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                }else{
                    $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($page < $num_pages) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $page + 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_next . '</a></li>';
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_last . '</a></li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        return $output;
    } else {
        return '';
    } 
        break;
        default:

    $total = $this->total;


    if ($this->page < 1) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $this->page;
    }

    if (!(int)$this->limit) {
        $limit = 10;
    } else {
        $limit = $this->limit;
    }

    $num_links = $this->num_links;
    $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

    $output = '<div class="pagination_wrap f_right">';

    if ($page > 1 && $page >= 3 && $num_pages > 3) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' .  $this->text_first . '</a>';
        if($page >= 3){
            $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
        }
    }

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
            $start = 1;
            $end = $num_pages;
        } else {
            $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
            $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

            if ($start < 1) {
                $end += abs($start) + 1;
                $start = 1;
            }

            if ($end > $num_pages) {
                $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                $end = $num_pages;
            }
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($page > 3 && $page < $num_pages && ($page < $num_pages-1 || $page < $num_pages-2) || $page < $num_pages-2) {
        $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
        if($num_pages > $num_pages-3){
        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $num_pages . '</a>';
        }
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        return $output;
    } else {
        return '';
    }

                break;
        }
        }else{
            $total = $this->total;


    if ($this->page < 1) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $this->page;
    }

    if (!(int)$this->limit) {
        $limit = 10;
    } else {
        $limit = $this->limit;
    }

    $num_links = $this->num_links;
    $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

    $output = '<div class="pagination_wrap f_right">';


    if ($page > 1 && ($page != 2 && $page != 3) || $page == 3) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' .  $this->text_first . '</a>';
        if($page > 3){
            $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
        }
    }

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
            $start = 1;
            $end = $num_pages;
        } else {
            $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
            $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

            if ($start < 1) {
                $end += abs($start) + 1;
                $start = 1;
            }

            if ($end > $num_pages) {
                $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                $end = $num_pages;
            }
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
            } else {
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($page > 3 && $page < $num_pages && ($page < $num_pages-1 || $page < $num_pages-2) || $page < $num_pages-2) {
        $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
        if($num_pages > $num_pages-3){
        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $num_pages . '</a>';
        }
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    if ($num_pages > 1) {
        return $output;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
        }
    }
}
```

category.tpl

```
 <?php echo $header; ?>
    <main>
    <section class="">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <?php
                $count_bread = count($breadcrumbs);
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
                    <?php if ($count != $count_bread) {
                        $count++; ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a> /
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <span><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if (isset($breadcrumbs[1]['catIdParent'])) {
                    $parentCat = $breadcrumbs[1]['catIdParent'];
                    $childCat = $breadcrumbs[1]['catIdChild'];
                } else {
                    $parentCat = '';
                    $childCat = '';
                }

                ?>
                <input type="hidden" id="parentCat" value="<?php echo $parentCat; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="childCat" value="<?php echo $childCat; ?>">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php if (!empty($categories)){ ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="category_page">
                <h3><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h3>
                <?php if ($categories) { ?>
                    <div class="wrap_subcategories">
                        <div class="col_links">
                            <?php $colonProd = ceil(count($categories) / 3); ?>
                            <?php
                            $count = 0;
                            foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                            <?php if (($count % $colonProd) == 0 && $count != 0){ ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col_links">
                            <?php } ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                            <?php $count++;
                            } ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <?php } ?>

     <?php if (empty($categories)) { ?>

        </div>
    <div class="container subcategory">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="filter_button">
                    <div>Показать фильтр</div>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                  </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <aside class="left_col">
                    <?= $column_left; ?>
                        <div class="left_section">
                            <div class="section_title">Торговая марка</div>
                            <ul class="manufacturer_filter">
                                <?php



                                if (!empty($data_manuf)) { ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($data_manuf as $key => $value) {

                                ?>
                                        <li data-href='<?= $url; ?>'>
                                            <label <?= (!empty($count_manufacturer) && array_key_exists($value['manufacturer_id'], $count_manufacturer)) ? '' : 'class="disabled"'; ?>>
                                                <input <?= (!empty($count_manufacturer) && array_key_exists($value['manufacturer_id'], $count_manufacturer)) ? '' : 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> value="<?= $value['manufacturer_id']; ?>"
                                                          type="checkbox" <?= (array_key_exists($value['manufacturer_id'], $count_manufacturer) && $value['checked']) ? $value['checked'] : ''; ?>>
                                                <span></span><?= $value['name']; ?>
                                                (<?= (!empty($count_manufacturer) && array_key_exists($value['manufacturer_id'], $count_manufacturer)) ? $count_manufacturer[$value['manufacturer_id']]['count'] : 0; ?>)</label>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php }
                                } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="left_section">
                            <div class="section_title">Цена</div>
                            <div class="range_wrap">
                                <div id="price-range-details" class="price-filter">
                                    <input type="text" id="price-range-low" value="" class="separator">
                                    <span class="range_text">-</span>
                                    <input type="text" id="price-range-high" value="">
                                    <span class="range_text" style="margin-right:0;">грн.</span>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="price-range" class="price-filter">
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-filter">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="needShow" value="<?= $products[0]['price'] ?>">
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function () {
                                            var minprice = $('#needShow').val();
                                            var isShown = minprice.split(' ');
                                            var yesShow = isShown[0] * 1;

                                            if (yesShow > 0) {
                                                $('#price-range').noUiSlider({
                                                    range: [<?= floor($start_price[0]['minprice']) != ceil($start_price[0]['maxprice']) ? floor($start_price[0]['minprice']) : 0; ?>, <?=ceil($start_price[0]['maxprice']) ?>],
                                                    start: [<?=(isset($min_price_sart)) ? floor($min_price_sart) : floor($start_price[0]['minprice']);?>,  <?=(isset($max_price_sart)) ? ceil($max_price_sart) : ceil($min_max_price[0]['maxprice']) ?>],
                                                    handles: 2,
                                                    connect: true,
                                                    step: 1,
                                                    serialization: {
                                                        to: [$('#price-range-low'), $('#price-range-high')],
                                                        resolution: 1
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </aside>
            </div>

            <?php
            /*echo "<pre>";
            print_r($products);
            <!-- print_r($sorts); -->
            echo "</pre>";*/
            ?>
            <?php if ($products) { ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                    <h2 class="title_page"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>
                    <div class="filter_select">
                        <div class="span_sort f_left">Отсортировано:</div>
                        <select>
                            <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
                                <?php if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"
                                            selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <span id="filterReturnZero" style="display: none;"><span class="no-item">Товаров с указанными характеристиками нет, повторите, пожалуйста, запрос с другими параметрами.</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row subcategory_list">
                        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                            <?php
                            /*echo '<pre>';
                            print_r($product);
                            echo '</pre>';
                            die();*/
                            ?>



                                <?php
                                $akciya = '';
                                if (!isset($akciya)) {
                                    $class = 'sale';
                                } elseif ($product['popular_product'] == 1) {
                                    $class = 'hit';
                                } elseif ($product['product_innovation'] == 1) {
                                    $class = 'new';
                                } else {
                                    $class = '';
                                }
                                if ($product['drawing_product'] == 1) {
                                    $class .= ' draw';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 items_prod">
                                    <div class="item <?= $class; ?>">
                                        <?php if (in_array($product['product_id'], $wishlist)) {
                                            $class_active = 'active';
                                            $wish = 'onclick="wishlist.remove(' . $product['product_id'] . ', this);" ontouchend="wishlist.add(' . $product['product_id'] . ', this);"';

                                        } else {
                                            $class_active = '';
                                            $wish = 'onclick="wishlist.add(' . $product['product_id'] . ', this);" ontouchend="wishlist.add(' . $product['product_id'] . ', this);"';
                                        } ?>
                                        <a class="liked <?= $class_active; ?>" <?= $wish; ?>><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>"
                                                 alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"
                                                 title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>">
                                            <div class="description_prod">
                                                <div class="name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></div>
                                                <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                                                    <div class="price"><?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                                                        <span>/ 1 <?= $product['weight_goods'] == 0 ? 'шт' : 'кг'; ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <div class="price"><?php echo $product['special']; ?> <span
                                                            class="price-old"> <?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                                                        <span>/ 1 <?= $product['weight_goods'] == 0 ? 'шт' : 'кг'; ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                <div class="opt_price">
                                                    <span><?= $product['disc_price']?></span>
                                                    <span>/ от <?= $product['disc_quantity']?>-х единиц</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="qtywrapper">
                                            <a class="decrease-qty">
                                                <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/img/minus.png">
                                            </a>
                                            <?php $numberProduct = $weight_goods == 0 ? '1' : $minimum; //echo $numberProduct;?>
                                            <input type="text" class="qty" value="<?= $product['weight_goods'] == 0 ? '1' : $product['minimum']; ?>"
                                                   data-step="<?= $product['weight_goods'] == 0 ? '1' : $product['minimum']; ?>"
                                                   step="<?= $product['weight_goods'] == 0 ? '1' : $product['minimum']; ?>" />
                                            <a class="increase-qty">
                                                <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/img/plus.png">
                                            </a>
                                            <span><?= $product['weight_goods'] == 0 ? 'шт' : 'кг'; ?></span>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="bottom_item">
                                            <a data-id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" class="global-add-to-cart"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i><span> В корзину</span></a>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control_block">
                        <div class="more_row">

                            <div class="pagination_text more">Показано <span></span> товаров
                                из <?php echo $countproducts; ?></div>
                            <div class="pagin_block">
                                <?php if ($pagination != '') { ?>
                                    <div class="pagin">
                                        <?php if ($load_more == true) { ?>
                                            <div class="more"><a class="load_more f_left" onclick="getNextPage(this);"
                                                                 ontouchend="getNextPage(this);"><span>Показать еще <?php echo $more; ?>
                                                        товаров</span></a>
    </div>
                                            <?php echo $pagination; ?>
                                        <?php } elseif ($pagination) { ?>
                                            <?php echo $pagination; ?>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                    <h2 class="title_page"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>
                    <div class="no-item">В этой категории ещё нет товаров</div>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: покажите код пагинации в шаблоне и контроллере

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev подскажите, где найти второй файл ? c opencart работаю второй день, пока не очень разбираюсь

Comment: `catalog/view/theme/default/product/category.tpl`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev добавил, спасибо

Comment: У вас пагинация вынесена из шаблона, гдето в другом шаблоне она, может в modules?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev где это можно найти ?
я ж говорю , просто сам я вряд ли найду

Comment: а, так она у вас вообще в контроллере, блин ну там адово много написано для простой пагинации, но подозреваю что первая 1 это `$this->text_first`.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev этот баг можно как-то исправить ?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я так понимаю ошибка здесь 
 if ($page > 1 && $page >= 3 && $num_pages > 3) {
   $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' .  $this->text_first . '</a>';
   if($page >= 3){
    $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
   }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос уже решён. Банально перебором вариантов количества отображаемых страниц.

```
<?php
class Pagination {
    public $total = 0;
    public $page = 1;
    public $limit = 9999;
    public $num_links = 3;
    public $url = '';
    public $text_first = '1';
    public $text_last = '&gt;|';
    public $text_next = '&gt;';
    public $text_prev = '&lt;';

    public function render() {

        if(isset($_GET['route'])){


            $takeArea = explode('/',$_GET['route']);

            switch ($takeArea[0]) {
                case 'catalog':
                case 'common':

                    $total = $this->total;

                    if ($this->page < 1) {
                        $page = 1;
                    } else {
                        $page = $this->page;
                    }

                    if (!(int)$this->limit) {
                        $limit = 10;
                    } else {
                        $limit = $this->limit;
                    }

                    $num_links = $this->num_links;
                    $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

                    $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

                    $output = '<ul class="pagination">';

                    if ($page > 1) {
                        $tmp_url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->url);
                        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', rtrim( str_replace('page={page}', '', $tmp_url), '?&')) . '">' . $this->text_first . '</a></li>';
                        if ($page == 2){
                            $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', rtrim( str_replace('page={page}', '', $tmp_url), '?&')) . '">' . $this->text_prev . '</a></li>';
                        }else{
                            $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $page - 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_prev . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    }

                    if ($num_pages > 1) {
                        if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
                            $start = 1;
                            $end = $num_pages;
                        } else {
                            $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
                            $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

                            if ($start < 1) {
                                $end += abs($start) + 1;
                                $start = 1;
                            }

                            if ($end > $num_pages) {
                                $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                                $end = $num_pages;
                            }
                        }

                        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                            if ($page == $i) {
                                $output .= '<li class="active"><span>' . $i . '</span></li>';
                            } else {
                                if ($i == 1){
                                    $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', rtrim( str_replace('page={page}', '', $tmp_url), '?&')) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                                }else{
                                    $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($page < $num_pages) {
                        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $page + 1, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_next . '</a></li>';
                        $output .= '<li><a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $this->text_last . '</a></li>';
                    }

                    $output .= '</ul>';

                    if ($num_pages > 1) {
                        return $output;
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                    break;
                default:

                    $total = $this->total;


                    if ($this->page < 1) {
                        $page = 1;
                    } else {
                        $page = $this->page;
                    }

                    if (!(int)$this->limit) {
                        $limit = 10;
                    } else {
                        $limit = $this->limit;
                    }

                    $num_links = $this->num_links;
                    $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

                    $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

                    $output = '<div class="pagination_wrap f_right">';

                    if ($page > 1 && $page >= 3 && $num_pages > 3) {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' .  $this->text_first . '</a>';
                        if($page >= 3){
                            $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                        }
                    }

                    if ($num_pages > 1) {
                        if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
                            $start = 1;
                            $end = $num_pages;
                        } else {
                            $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
                            $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

                            if ($start < 1) {
                                $end += abs($start) + 1;
                                $start = 1;
                            }

                            if ($end > $num_pages) {
                                $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                                $end = $num_pages;
                            }
                        }

                        for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                            if ($page == $i) {
                                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                                // $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
                            } else {
                                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($page > 3 && $page < $num_pages && ($page < $num_pages-1 || $page < $num_pages-2) || $page < $num_pages-2) {
                        $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                        if($num_pages > $num_pages-3){
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $num_pages . '</a>';
                        }
                    }

                    $output .= '</div>';

                    if ($num_pages > 1) {
                        return $output;
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }else{
            $total = $this->total;


            if ($this->page < 1) {
                $page = 1;
            } else {
                $page = $this->page;
            }

            if (!(int)$this->limit) {
                $limit = 10;
            } else {
                $limit = $this->limit;
            }

            $num_links = $this->num_links;
            $num_pages = ceil($total / $limit);

            $this->url = str_replace('%7Bpage%7D', '{page}', $this->url);

            //-----------------------------------New
//            $page;//текущий пейдж
//            $num_pages;//всего пейджей
//            $num_links;//количество кубиков которое показывать
            $output = '<div class="pagination_wrap f_right">';
            if($num_links != 5) $num_links = 5;
            if($page > $num_pages) $page = $num_pages;
            if($num_pages <= $num_links){
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++){
                    if ($page == $i) {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if($page <= 3){
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                        if ($page == $i) {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
                        } else {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                    $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                    $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $num_pages . '</a>';
                }elseif($page >= ($num_pages - 2)){
                    $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' . 1 . '</a>';
                    $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                    for ($i = ($num_pages - 3); $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
                        if ($page == $i) {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
                        } else {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                }else{// page > 3 но page < num_pages-2
                    $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' . 1 . '</a>';
                    $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                    for ($i = ($page - ( ($num_links-3)/2 )); $i <= ($page + ( ($num_links-3)/2 )); $i++) {//требует доработки если num_links нужен больше 5ти ВАЖНО!!! чтоб нум линкс был не четный 7,9,11... тогда все будет хорошо! иначе получим страницу 5 с половиной!!!
                        if ($page == $i) {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
                        } else {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                    $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                    $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $num_pages . '</a>';
                }
            }


            $output .= '</div>';
            if ($num_pages > 1) {//пагинация показывается только если пейджей 2 и больше
                return $output;
            }else{
                return '';
            }
            //-----------------------------------end New
            if ($page > 3)  { // 1...
                $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' .  $this->text_first . '</a>';
                if($page > 3){
                    $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                }
            }

            if ($num_pages > 1) {
                if ($num_pages <= $num_links) {
                    $start = 1;
                    $end = $num_pages;
                } else {
                    $start = $page - floor($num_links / 2);
                    $end = $page + floor($num_links / 2);

                    if ($start < 1) {
                        $end += abs($start) + 1;
                        $start = 1;
                    }

                    if ($end > $num_pages) {
                        $start -= ($end - $num_pages);
                        $end = $num_pages;
                    }
                }

                for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
                    if ($page == $i) {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '" class="active">' . $i . '</a>';
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i + 1, $this->url) . '" class="smore-product" style="display:none;"></a>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $i, $this->url) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($page > 3 && $page < $num_pages && ($page < $num_pages-1 || $page < $num_pages-2) || $page < $num_pages-2) {
                $output .= '<span href="#" class="more">...</span>';
                if($num_pages > $num_pages-3){
                    $output .= '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', $num_pages, $this->url) . '">' . $num_pages . '</a>';
                }
            }
            if ($page == 3 && $page < $num_pages) {
                $outfist = '<a href="' . str_replace('{page}', 1, $this->url) . '">' .  $this->text_first . '</a>';
                $output = str_replace('<div class="pagination_wrap f_right">', '<div class="pagination_wrap f_right">'.$outfist, $output);
            }

            $output .= '</div>';

            if ($num_pages > 1) {
                return $output;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Андрей это решение вопроса, опубликованное самим автором вопроса.